# ASP.NET MVC 5 web application starts throwing errors after some time after deployment. Solved by editing any file

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have the most peculiar problem with my ASP.NET MVC 5 app written in C#.

I have deployed many apps which are basically the same as this one internally. The last one, however behaves very strange.

I deploy the app and everything works well for about 30 minutes up to an hour or so. Then the site starts throwing errors. But errors in my code, like a Linq function throwing "No objects in sequence" after logging in.

However! If I open the app folder on our IIS and open `web.config` (it can be any of the app files, though), add like one extra empty line to it and save it, it all starts working again for an hour or so.

What is even happening? More importantly, how could just saving one file again fix the problem?

Thanks for any discussion.

EDIT: When I don't edit the file and wait about an hour, it starts working again.

Comment: There's a bug somewhere that shows up after some time. By editing the web.config you restart the application pool and thus, the app needs time to go awry. Carefully inspect what's going on, however, I suspect you are not **disposing** your database objects correctly and the app depletes resources.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I think you're pointing me in the right direction. How would troubleshoot this on the production server? When I launch the app in VS on my local PC it always works fine, but I feel like I don't need to mention that. Thank you

Comment: @WiktorZychla editing web.config only triggers ASP.NET runtime to reload. That's not application pool restart/recycle, so don't misunderstand the concepts.

Comment: Running a web app on your local machine is usually the simplest scenario (almost zero load). So if everything is fine then, you can only confirm the very basic functionalities work. Hosting on a production server with some load can break badly written applications easily, since operations by multiple users can amplify all kinds of bottlenecks. Experienced developers can tell what might be wrong from the exact errors (but you didn't post any), or use profilers. So in your case, escalate to a senior developer in your team or hire a consultant from outside.

Comment: @LexLi: that's correct, it reloads the app and not the pool. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: After re-editing the file, the application is reloaded, and the instances, database connection objects, etc. in the application will be re-initialized. So it's not that saving the file solves the problem, it's the app re-running. You should focus on the error message and code mentioned in the error and show the relevant code.

Comment: @BruceZhang I have "solved" the problem. I have been using a Singleton object which I registered in my services via dependency injection. That has been the first time I did that and since I removed it, it started working without problems. So I have to research Singleton object in .NET apps now. Thank you for your answer.